# Online algorithms for MSTs from time series

Tags: algorithms, spanning-tree

Is it possible to construct the MST (minimum-weight spanning tree) for an potentially infinite sequence of points $\lbrace (i,Y[i]): i\in\mathbb{N}_0,\,c_{\text{min}} \le Y[i]\le c_{\text{max}}\rbrace$ with a sweep-line algorithm when only the bounds for the values of the $Y[i]$ are known?